# wait for response from promise to populate form

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

Hello I am working on an angular/typescript application, I have read about the `promise`s but it is not clear to me please of your help.

have function `getUserById()` return user information, and `getAttributeByUserId()`, so i need fill form from two functions but the variables on `getAttribute` are `undefinied`, here is my code.

Angular / Typescript

```
getUserById(userId, modalContent) {
  console.log('get user by id ' + userId);
  const config = AppConfiguration.CONFIG_GET_USERS_BY_ID;
  config.user_id = userId;
  const date = new Date();
  this._httpService.CountUsers().post(config).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log('resultado al obtener usuario editado ' + data[0].user_id);
    this.userForm.patchValue({'firstName': data[0].firstname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'secondName': data[0].secondname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'lastName': data[0].lastname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'mothersLastName': data[0].motherslastname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'birthDay': {
      date: {
        year: data[0].birthday.substring(0, 4),
        month: data[0].birthday.substring(5, 7),
        day: data[0].birthday.substring(8, 10)}
    }});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'roleId': data[0].role_id});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'email': data[0].email});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'userId': data[0].user_id});
    this.open(modalContent);
    // this.open(modalContent);
  });
}

getAttributeByUserId(userId: number) {
  const config = AppConfiguration.CONFIG_GET_ATTRIBUTE_BY_ID;
  config.user_id = userId;
  this._httpService.CountUsers().post(config).subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.attributes = data;
  });
}
```

I need call `getAttributeByUserId` inside `getUserById` and get the data.

Comment: `I need call getAttributeByUserId inside getUserById and get the data.` <= Ok so why not do that? I do not see any calls to this method in the code you have shared. `the variables on getAttribute are undefinied` <= what variables are undefined exactly?

Comment: Hello @Igor thanks for response, i update the code, the variable this.attributes are undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change the functions

```
getUserById(userId, modalContent) {
console.log('get user by id ' + userId);
const config = AppConfiguration.CONFIG_GET_USERS_BY_ID;
config.user_id = userId;
const date = new Date();
this._httpService.CountUsers().post(config).subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log('resultado al obtener usuario editado ' + data[0].user_id);
  this.userForm.patchValue({'firstName': data[0].firstname});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'secondName': data[0].secondname});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'lastName': data[0].lastname});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'mothersLastName': data[0].motherslastname});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'birthDay': {
    date: {
        year: data[0].birthday.substring(0, 4),
        month: data[0].birthday.substring(5, 7),
        day: data[0].birthday.substring(8, 10)}
    }});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'roleId': data[0].role_id});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'email': data[0].email});
  this.userForm.patchValue({'userId': data[0].user_id});
  this.getAttributeByUserId(data[0].user_id).then((response) => {
    console.log('respueta del ws attribuete' + JSON.stringify(response));
    this.open(modalContent);
  });
  // this.open(modalContent);
});
```

}

```
getAttributeByUserId(userId: number) {
const config = AppConfiguration.CONFIG_GET_ATTRIBUTE_BY_ID;
config.user_id = userId;
this._httpService.CountUsers().post(config).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.attributes = data;
});
return Promise.resolve(this.attributes);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your answer it is more clear what it was you are asking. You need to return an observable that you can subscribe to from `getAttributeByUserId`. If you still want to push the returned value into `attributes` then you can do that either in that method using `tap` which allows you to execute code without altering the returned result before the subscribe callback is executed **or** you can let the caller take care of that in the `subscribe` call back. I chose the former.

Another critical recommendation while you are learning how to develop using typescript / angular: Learn to use strong types. This can save you in run time errors later on which are more difficult to debug or catch. I inferred that there is some interface or class named `Attribute` below, if you do not have one yet I recommend using an interface (common practice for data structures returned from http calls).

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


getUserById(userId, modalContent) {
  console.log('get user by id ' + userId);
  const config = AppConfiguration.CONFIG_GET_USERS_BY_ID;
  config.user_id = userId;
  const date = new Date();
  this._httpService.CountUsers().post(config).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log('resultado al obtener usuario editado ' + data[0].user_id);
    this.userForm.patchValue({'firstName': data[0].firstname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'secondName': data[0].secondname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'lastName': data[0].lastname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'mothersLastName': data[0].motherslastname});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'birthDay': {
      date: {
        year: data[0].birthday.substring(0, 4),
        month: data[0].birthday.substring(5, 7),
        day: data[0].birthday.substring(8, 10)}
    }});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'roleId': data[0].role_id});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'email': data[0].email});
    this.userForm.patchValue({'userId': data[0].user_id});

    this.getAttributeByUserId(userId).subscribe((attributes) => {
      this.open(modalContent);
    });
  });
}

getAttributeByUserId(userId: number) : Observable<Attribute[]> {
  const config = AppConfiguration.CONFIG_GET_ATTRIBUTE_BY_ID;
  config.user_id = userId;
  return this._httpService.CountUsers().post<Attribute[]>(config).pipe(tap((data) => {
    this.attributes = data;
  }));
}
```